# Asp.net + Razor 2 + MySQL & iFrame Displaying

Tags: asp.net, mysql, iframe

Okay so basically I want to display iframes (movie iframes) from my MySQL Database
But I want to display the iframe on button click (via AJAX?)

When I put create an iframe for a movie in the database and call the certain iframe with Razor2 (WebMatrix), I get the iframe source code not the actual (JwPlayer/Flash/Movie Player) that would originally show if I put the source of the iframe in a regular html doc.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Html.Raw(<your source from the database>)
```

Use the Raw method to render the iframe source code to valid HTML.

Comment: QQping another question do i do @Html.raw("@movie.Name")
or do i put the iframe there inside the ("")

Comment: You have to put the iframe sourcecode into the .Raw! So if the iframe code is stored inside movie.iframecode then you have to call `@Html.Raw(movie.iframecode)`